# Geb: How to add new attribute and its value

Tags: selenium, automation, attributes, set, geb

I have an input element where I need to set one extra attribute and its value.

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="to_input" name="to" class="form-control arrival ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="To" data-input-component="searchCondition" data-input-support="suggest" type="text">
```

I need to add the below attribute:
[image]

How can I do this in Geb?

To say a little more  details, when I enter TPE in the input text box, some dropdown items appears and when I select one of them like

```
"Taipei, XXX..  (TPE)"
```

Than the new attributes are set automatically same as the picture above.

Comment: Then automate the text box interaction, don't mess with the DOM manually. That would not be a good test.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it, is using JavaScript executor:

```
browser.driver.executeScript("your script")
```

And script using jquery will look like:

```
$('jquery-selector').attr('attribute-name', 'attribute-value');
```

**Of course make sure to fill in your data in quotes!**